# Is it possible to use neighbors command with agent routing?

Tags: netlogo

I have a question: I have a model that has an agent with a bee shape. In one part of the code the bee checks its eight neighbors (using the "neighbors" command) and goes to the neighbor that has the highest value of a patch variable. The point is that aesthetically it is weird, because at times this agent moves backwards with his head forward. I wanted to know if there is any way this agent can use the command "neighbors" to choose the patch with the highest value to turn to this one and move?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're looking for `face`. You can do something like `let target max-one-of neighbors [value] face target move-to target`.

Comment: Thanks Matteo. Well remembering. I was wanting to use heading that wouldn't be possible. Thank you. It helped a lot. I won't forget this command anymore :)